# ControlsFX: CheckComboBox Popup Styling

Tags: javafx, popup, controlsfx

I am trying to style the actual popup menu (not the cells, because I believe I can style those).

I have tried using the ".combo-box-popup" selector and the ".combo-box-popup .list-view" selector to no avail.

I believe this is because the CheckComboBox delegates to an internal ComboBox and so the usual styling doesn't work, but I may be wrong.

I have even tried (after searching through the code) to get "at" the popup itself but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

I am only able to style the gray button cell by calling "setStyle()" on the internal ComboBox within my derived skin class (I copied all the needed code from CheckComboBoxSkin to make a derived CheckColorComboBoxSkin class) which is nearly identical to the parent class except for creating list cell factories which allow me to return a special ListCell for including other things than just the check box and description.

Those things are not "in the way" however and are not relevant except to explain how I am able to call setStyle() directly on the internal delegate ComboBox to style the box itself (not the popup).

My problem however is trying to find a way to style the popup, is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
David